# Access to listbox in static method

Tags: c#, windows-8, static, listbox, windows-store-apps

I have one static method which I call from another class when I need update data in listbox. But then I need scroll listbox to last item. Here is code:

```
 public static void updateMessages()
  {
      MyDatasCurentUser.Clear();//clear messages from previewous user from datas
      foreach (var items in UniDB.returnlistOfMessagesData(IdOfChoosenUser, MainContentPage.myID))
      {
          _mydataCurentUser.Add(new BindingData
          {
              MessengerReadTime = new DateTime(items.readTime.Year, items.readTime.Month, items.readTime.Day, items.readTime.Hour, items.readTime.Minute, 0),
              MessengeFullName = items.senderName,
              MessengerTime = new DateTime(items.sendTime.Year, items.sendTime.Month, items.sendTime.Day, items.sendTime.Hour, items.sendTime.Minute, 0).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm"),
              MessengerMessage = items.message,
              MessengerIsFromMe = items.isFromMe,
          });
      }

      lbChoosenMessagesUsers.ScrollIntoView(lbChoosenMessagesUsers.Items.Last());
  }
```

But I get error **cannot access to non static field in static context** at this: `lbChoosenMessagesUsers.ScrollIntoView(lbChoosenMessagesUsers.Items.Last());`

Is there any way how I can do this `lbChoosenMessagesUsers.ScrollIntoView(lbChoosenMessagesUsers.Items.Last());` when is method updateMessages() called?

Comment: Make method not static or pass it `lbChoosenMessagesUsers` as parameter.

Comment: you shouldn't have this method as static

Comment: So If I change it to non static method how I can call this method from another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a non static method of one class:

```
class Form1
{
   public void UpdateMessages()
   {   
       // ...
       lbChoosenMessagesUsers.ScrollIntoView(lbChoosenMessagesUsers.Items.Last());
   }
}
```

And you want to call it from an object of a different class, that object will need a reference to the first object. A common solution is to pass the reference to the first object into the constructor of the second:

```
class OtherClass
{  
   Form1 _form;
   OtherClass(Form1 form)
   {
       _form = form;
   }

   void Method()
   {
       //can access the methods of the other object
       _form.UpdateMessages();
   }
}
```

Alternatively you could pass the object in later:

```
class OtherClass
{  
   public void Method(Form1 form)
   {
       form.UpdateMessages();
   }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant guide. THX.